# Como puedo hacer diez peticiones diferentes a un servidor por ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hola tengo un servidor que me da un palabra aleaoria y al crear un bucle siempre me da la misma palabra y no se como hacer que me de diez palabras distintas.
Aqui el codigo:

```
var palabra = "";

function Creapalabra() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            palabra = JSON.parse(this.responseText).word;
            palabra = palabra.replace(/á/gi, "a");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/é/gi, "e");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/í/gi, "i");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ó/gi, "o");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ú/gi, "u");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ü/gi, "u");
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://daw.aitordb.com:4000", true);
    xhttp.send();
}


function inicio() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Creapalabra();
        document.getElementById("palabra" + i).innerHTML = palabra;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has algo. Intenta declarar la variable `var palabra` dentro de la condicion `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)` y dime que ocurre.

Comment: si la meto ahí dentro no es accesible desde la función inicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas, el problema que estás teniendo es que las peticiones son asíncronas, una solución es crear una promesa y mostrarlo cuando van llegando

**Solución**

```js
function Creapalabra(i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var palabra = JSON.parse(this.responseText).word;
            palabra = palabra.replace(/á/gi, "a");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/é/gi, "e");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/í/gi, "i");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ó/gi, "o");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ú/gi, "u");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ü/gi, "u");

           resolve({palabra, numero: i});
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://daw.aitordb.com:4000", true);
    xhttp.send();
         });
}

    function inicio() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Creapalabra(i).then((data) => {
                document.getElementById("palabra" + data.numero).innerHTML += data.palabra;
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta aislar el resultado para que el valor palabra sea único por cada peticion utilizando un callback:

```
function Creapalabra(callback) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var palabra = JSON.parse(this.responseText).word;
            palabra = palabra.replace(/á/gi, "a");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/é/gi, "e");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/í/gi, "i");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ó/gi, "o");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ú/gi, "u");
            palabra = palabra.replace(/ü/gi, "u");

            callback(palabra);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://daw.aitordb.com:4000", true);
    xhttp.send();
}


function inicio() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Creapalabra(function(palabra){
              document.getElementById("palabra" + i).innerHTML += palabra;
        });
    }
}
```

Probablemente los valores de la variable `palabra` estan siendo sobre escrito debido a que es global  y como las peticiones son asíncronas, no necesariamente se ejecuten en orden.

Comment: index.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at index.js:25
    at XMLHttpRequest.Creapalabra.xhttp.onreadystatechange (index.js:13)

Comment: Quiere decir que el elemento html con el id palabra1... palabra10 no existen. Seguro que los estas creando?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hologrifo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="inicio()" value="Empezar">
    <div id="palabra0"></div>
    <div id="palabra1"></div>
    <div id="palabra2"></div>
    <div id="palabra3"></div>
    <div id="palabra4"></div>
    <div id="palabra5"></div>
    <div id="palabra6"></div>
    <div id="palabra7"></div>
    <div id="palabra8"></div>
    <div id="palabra9"></div>
</body>

</html>

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer recursión cuando la petición finalice así no sobrecargas el servidor. Algo así sería:

```
function Creapalabra(i) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();      
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var palabra = JSON.parse(this.responseText).word;
          palabra = palabra.replace(/á/gi, "a");
          palabra = palabra.replace(/é/gi, "e");
          palabra = palabra.replace(/í/gi, "i");
          palabra = palabra.replace(/ó/gi, "o");
          palabra = palabra.replace(/ú/gi, "u");
          palabra = palabra.replace(/ü/gi, "u");

          document.getElementById("palabra" + i).innerHTML += palabra;
          if (i < 10) Creapalabra(i++);
      }
  } 
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://daw.aitordb.com:4000", true);
  xhttp.send();  
}

function inicio() {
    Creapalabra(1);        
}
```